# How to set radio button to follow the saved value in db?

Tags: android, kotlin

First of all, I'm a total newbie in the world of Kotlin and Android development. But, following an example I managed to create and modify a backend (back4app) for my needs and also created a small Android app connected to it.

I have a three-button radio group that presents status (Open, Ongoing, Closed). The selected value is saved to db, that's working. But when opening the item, the button is not set according to the saved value. The selected button is always the first one. I've run out of ideas and knowledge.

Don't care about the hard-coded silly icons, it is just for testing purposes. Getting real ones is another story...

I don't know the difference between other fields, since they are showing the saved value correctly.

Added code for db fetch.

Code (imports removed):

```
package com.example.cyclisthelp

...

class FormActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    private val viewModel = AppViewModel.getInstance()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val objectId = intent.getStringExtra("objectId")
        val cfh = if (objectId !== null) viewModel.CallForHelps.value[objectId] else null

        setContent {
            FormActivityContent(
                cfh,
                onAddClick = { icon: String, title: String, description: String, status: String ->
                    if (cfh !== null) return@FormActivityContent
                    val newCFH = CallForHelp(
                        icon = icon,
                        title = title,
                        description = description,
                        status = status
                    )
                    newCFH.addToParse {
                        viewModel.CallForHelps.value += (it to newCFH)
                        finish()
                    }
                },
                onSaveClick = { icon: String, title: String, description: String, status: String ->
                    if (cfh === null) return@FormActivityContent
                    val updatedCFH = cfh.copy()
                    updatedCFH.icon = icon
                    updatedCFH.title = title
                    updatedCFH.description = description
                    updatedCFH.status = status
                    updatedCFH.updateToParse {
                        viewModel.CallForHelps.value += (it to updatedCFH)
                        finish()
                    }
                },
                onDeleteClick = {
                    if (cfh === null) return@FormActivityContent
                    viewModel.CallForHelps.value = viewModel.CallForHelps.value.filter {
                        it.value.objectId != cfh.objectId
                    }
                    cfh.deleteFromParse {
                        finish()
                    }
                },
            )
        }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun FormActivityContent(
    callforhelp: CallForHelp?,
    onAddClick: (icon: String, title: String, description: String, status: String) -> Unit,
    onSaveClick: (icon: String, title: String, description: String, status: String) -> Unit,
    onDeleteClick: () -> Unit,
) {
    MaterialTheme {
        Scaffold(
            topBar = {
                TopAppBar(title = { Text(callforhelp?.let { "Edit row" } ?: ("Add row")) })
            },
            floatingActionButton = {
                if (callforhelp !== null) {
                    ExtendedFloatingActionButton(
                        onClick = { onDeleteClick() },
                        icon = { Icon(Icons.Filled.Delete, "Delete") },
                        text = { Text("Delete") },
                    )
                }
            },
        ) { contentPadding ->
            Box(modifier = Modifier.padding(contentPadding)) {
                CfhForm(callforhelp = callforhelp, onSave = { icon, title, description, status ->
                    if (callforhelp === null) {
                        onAddClick(icon, title, description, status)
                    } else {
                        onSaveClick(icon, title, description, status)
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun CfhForm(
    callforhelp: CallForHelp?,
    onSave: (icon: String, title: String, description: String, status: String) -> Unit
) {
    var title by remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue(callforhelp?.title ?: "")) }
    var description by remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue(callforhelp?.description ?: "")) }

    val radioOptions = listOf("Open","Ongoing","Closed")
    var status by remember { mutableStateOf(radioOptions[0]) }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(16.dp)
    ) {

//        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp).padding(0.dp))
        radioOptions.forEach { caseStatus ->

            Row(verticalAlignment=Alignment.CenterVertically) {
                RadioButton(
                    selected = (caseStatus == status),
                    onClick = {
                        status = caseStatus
                    }
                )
                Text(
                    text = caseStatus,
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyLarge,
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 3.dp)
                )
            }
        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
        TextField(
            label = { Text(text = "Title") },
            value = title,
            onValueChange = { title = it },
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
        TextField(
            label = { Text(text = "Content") },
            value = description,
            onValueChange = { description = it },
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
        )

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
        Button(
            onClick = {

                var icon: String ="C"

                if (status === "Open"){
                    icon = "O"
                }
                if (status === "Ongoing"){
                    icon = "G"
                }
                if (status === "Closed"){
                    icon = "C"
                }

                onSave(icon, title.text, description.text, status )
            },
            Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
        ) {
            Text(text = "Save")
        }
    }
}

=== DB fetch ===


    init {
        val query = com.parse.ParseQuery.getQuery<com.parse.ParseObject>("CallForHelp")
        query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
        query.findInBackground { cfhs, e ->
            if (e == null) {
                for (parseCFH in cfhs) {
                    val cfh = CallForHelp(
                        objectId = parseCFH.objectId,
                        icon = parseCFH.getString("Icon")!!,
                        title = parseCFH.getString("Title")!!,
                        description = parseCFH.getString("Description")!!,
                        status = parseCFH.getString("Status")!!,
                    )
                    this.CallForHelps.value += (cfh.objectId!! to cfh)
                }
            } else {
                println("Error: ${e.message}")
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The important part would be in the view model.

But let's have a look at you data source first. The database should return a `Flow` that always emits a new value when the data in the database is changed. Since I do not know what database you use and what your database entities look like, let's assume you have a Room database with this DAO:

```
@Dao
interface CallForHelpDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM cfh")
    fun getAll(): Flow<List<CallForHelp>>
}
```

(It looks like you use a map instead of a list, but that would just work the same.)

Now to the important part in the view model. With an instance of your database you can define a new property in the view model like this:

```
val callForHelps: StateFlow<List<CallForHelp>> =
    database.callForHelpDao().getAll().stateIn(
        scope = viewModelScope,
        started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5_000),
        initialValue = emptyList(),
    )
```

This will always represent the current value from the database, in this case a list of all CallForHelps. In your composables, this list can now be collected from the flow and displayed accordingly:

```
val cfhs : List<CallForHelp> by viewModel.callForHelps.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
```

(needs this dependency: `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-compose`)

Remember, this must be called from a composable, so this has to be at least in the `setContent` block or somewhere further down in the compose tree. `cfhs` is now a simple list and contains all CallForHelp objects stored in the database. It will also always be the most *current* list of CallForHelps. As soon as something is changed in the database, this will automatically update and trigger a new composition. Just retrieve the object you need from the list and do with it whatever you want. It will always be the current version from the database.